# Compare 2 characters in a string (haskell)

Tags: haskell

my function should return the longest prefix consisting of the same character. For example:
"aaaabc" == "aaaa" or "abc" == "a"

How can I compare the first character with the rest of the characters?

My idea:

```
testString :: String -> String
testString input = 
if head input == head (tail input) then testString (input)
else head [input]
```

I should use only the keywords: tail, head, ++ or :

Comment: Hint: as soon as you call this function recursively with only the tail of the string, the recursive call has no way to know what the original first character was. You might need a second function.

Comment: What should the second function contain?

Comment: Hint: its signature should be `Char -> String -> Int`. It returns how many copies of the `Char` occur at the start of the `String`.

Comment: My function works now, thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post it as an answer so that other people might be helped by it :)

Answer (score -1):

You can have one function that splits an array into two chunks: a chunk that contains elements equal to a value, and the rest, then you can recursively check and find the max:

```hs
takeEqual :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
takeEqual _ [] = ([], [])
takeEqual v (x:xs)
    | x == v = let (equals, rest) = takeEqual v xs
                in (v:equals, rest)
    | otherwise = ([], x:xs)

testString :: String -> String
testString "" = ""
testString x =
    -- find the set of contiguous characters at the start
    let (substr, rest) = takeEqual (head x) x
        -- recursively find the longest set of contiguous characters past this one
        otherSubstr = testString rest
     -- return the longer of the two
     in if length otherSubstr > length substr
            then otherSubstr
            else substr
```